# Decode string iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I'm using listing to get the content of an ftp site, and it works fine, but in some cases, i have files with special chars in their names, like this one: "Márzo 2 2013 (8).JPG", the second char. When i call the listing function y get a NSDictionary with this data (using nslog):

```
{
  kCFFTPResourceGroup = group;
  kCFFTPResourceLink = "";
  kCFFTPResourceModDate = "2013-03-09 19:08:00 +0000";
  kCFFTPResourceMode = 511;
  kCFFTPResourceName = "M\U00b7rzo 2 2013 (8).JPG";
  kCFFTPResourceOwner = owner;
  kCFFTPResourceSize = 145971;
  kCFFTPResourceType = 8;
}
```

then using this

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[listaArchivos objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:(id)kCFFTPResourceName]);
```

i get

```
M·rzo 2 2013 (8).JPG
```

notice the second char, it should be "á", i tried a lot of funcions but i can't convert correctly my string, i hope someone can help

Thanks.

Ezequiel.

Comment: It's just that NSLog can't stand string encodings. Write the string to a file, view it in a decent text editor, and it'll be fine.

Comment: It need to be displayed in the log, because i use the file name to download the file, and when i try the download, i get an error because the file name is wrong

Comment: I realized that "M\U00b7rzo 2 2013 (8).JPG" converted is "M·rzo 2 2013 (8).JPG", but in the ftp server the file name is "Márzo 2 2013 (8).JPG", why the listing function can't read the actual value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was on the function that gets the dictionary, I could fix it watching the simpleFTPSample from apple, in the file ListController.m in the function - (void)parseListData, i change this line

```
entryToAdd = [self entryByReencodingNameInEntry:(__bridge NSDictionary *) thisEntry encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];//NSUTF8StringEncoding
```

I changed utf8 with ascii, and now i can get the filename correctly.
The problem now, is that the file can't be downloaded.

In this line, from the same file of the example

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode 
    ·
    ·
        bytesRead = [self.networkStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
        if (bytesRead < 0) {
            [self stopReceiveWithStatus:@"Network read error"];
        } else if (bytesRead == 0) {
            [self stopReceiveWithStatus:nil];
        } else {
            assert(self.listData != nil);

            // Append the data to our listing buffer.

            [self.listData appendBytes:buffer length:(NSUInteger) bytesRead];

            // Check the listing buffer for any complete entries and update 
            // the UI if we find any.

            [self parseListData];
        }
```

I'm getting the "Netwok read error", the filestream creates the file in the documents folder, the netwokstreamdown opens, but it can't be read, some advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Problem solved, all was a problem with the different encoding type, but it was difficult to track the origin. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code

```
NSString *sourcestr = @"ë,à,é,ä all to e,a,e,a";
NSData *temp = [sourcestr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *outputStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:temp encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
NSLog(@"converted: %@", outputStr);
```

Its work fine for me